# How to hide some of the content of HTML/JS page but need to show it at the time of print?

Tags: javascript, html

I want to hide some of the content of my result page but want to show when i am printing the page using window.print() is it possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can add css media print.

if not print you can set display to none, and if print change display.

```css
div {
 display : none;
}

@media print {
  div{
    display : block;
  }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you wanna run some code before / after printing, there are some global events you can subscribe to.

Check this out for stuff before printing: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onbeforeprint

And this for stuff after printing: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowEventHandlers/onafterprint

Esentially what you wanna do is listen to those event and manipulate the DOM according to what you want :)